# ER diagram for chemical reactions

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have to design a database for storing data for chemical reactions. I have 3 entities: chemical, reaction and conditions.

I have also designed the ER diagram. But it doesn't seem perfect. Please indicate the flaws and suggest improvement for the following ER diagram.

[image]

Comment: Why are you in doubt? Are the attributes predefined? Have you tried out some queries and checked if your schema can produce satisfying results?

Comment: I really can't understand how relations are used in constructing tables. I have these entities and their attributes, with them I'm able to make all the necessary queries. I don't understand the use of relations in constructing tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be a relation between reaction and condition as reactions occur at particular conditions and also you have to specify type of relationship.

Comment: what about that between reaction and chemical? a chemical can be a reactant as well as a product. How is that getting represented in this diagram?

Comment: you have to make another relationship between chemical and reaction. i.e. chemicals--undergoes---reactions

Comment: so another link? is that possible that 2 enities have 2 relations? if yes, i suppose they'll be in opposite directions.

Comment: yes it can have and in Er diagram direction of relationship is not shown and not onliy this an entity can have relationship with itself.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the relation between Chemicals, Reactions and Conditions should be ternary and one more relation between Reactions and Chemicals to represent the produced chemicals. Here is the statement: "Chemicals react under certain conditions. The reaction produces chemicals."

Here is a way to represent it:

[image: Ternary relation]

But as figure 3.8 in this site http://www.databasedesign.co.uk/bookdatabasesafirstcourse/chap3/chap3.htm describes this relation can be further broken down into a collection of binary relations. Here is the final ER:
[image: Ternary relation using 2 binary relations]

Your tables should look something like this:

```
    CHEMICALS(chemicalId, ...)
    REACTIONS(reactionId, conditionId,...) [conditionId here represents the 1-M "UNDER"]
    CONDITIONS(confitionId, ...)
    CHEMICALS_REACT(reactionId, chemicalId) [This table represents the M-M "REACT"]
    REACTION_PROD_CHEM(reactionId, chemicalId) [This table represents the M-M "PRODUCE"]
```